# Правильно ли организовано использование INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Есть в БД 3 таблицы:

- Accounts (хранит информацию юзера)
- Companies (хранит информацию компаний)
- Employees (хранит id аккаунта и id компании для связи аккаунта и компании)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует одноименный объект Java с именем **Employee**, который хранится в сесии у юзера.
Цель - по employee_id понять что за аккаунт и к какой фирме относится.

Создал хранимую процедуру, принимающую два аргумента: company_id и account_id для получения информации из двух таблиц БД одним запросом:

```sql
// хранимая процедура, назовем её get_information
create
    definer = root@localhost procedure get_information(IN companyId bigint unsigned, IN accountID bigint unsigned)
BEGIN
    SELECT company_name, account_first_name, account_last_name, account_login
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN companies ON company_id = companyId AND account_id = accountId;
end;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    company_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(account_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies(company_id)
);
```

**Вопрос 1:**
Правильно ли организован JOIN? Если нет, то как правильно?

**Вопрос2:**
Либо правильне будет создать два SELECT и объединить их UNION?

Comment: "Цель - по employee_id понять что за аккаунт и к какой фирме относится." - Объект `Employee`  (объект Java класса) хранится в сесиии. Из сессии достаем объект `Employee` таким образом `Employee employee = (Employee) session.getAttribute(EMPLOYEE)`. Когда дастали объект,  делаем Employee.getId() и получаем id. Далее, по этому id ищем уже в БД в таблице `Employees` id аккаунта и id компании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. никто не предлагает, один из вариантов решения:

```sql
SELECT
  c.company_name,
  a.account_login
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN accounts a on a.account_id = e.account_id
INNER JOIN companies c on c.company_id = e.company_id
WHERE e.employee_id = 3
```